# How to automatically jump to next input field

Tags: javascript, blazor

i am trying to create an input field with 6 inputs:

```js
function focusNext(currentInput, nextIndex) {
  if (currentInput.value.length === 1) {
    const nextInput = document.querySelector(`input:nth-child(${nextIndex})`);
    if (nextInput) {
      nextInput.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="code-input">
  <input type="text" @bind=code0 maxlength="1" onkeyup="focusNext(this, 1)">
  <input type="text" @bind=code1 maxlength="1" onkeyup="focusNext(this, 2)">
  <input type="text" @bind=code2 maxlength="1" onkeyup="focusNext(this, 3)">
  <input type="text" @bind=code3 maxlength="1" onkeyup="focusNext(this, 4)">
  <input type="text" @bind=code4 maxlength="1" onkeyup="focusNext(this, 5)">
  <input type="text" @bind=code5 maxlength="1">
</div>
```

I want it to automatically jump to the next input field, once the previous one is filled out.

But just nothing happens.
As this is inside a blazor context, I cannot use jquery.

Can someone spot my error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using querySelector, consider using querySelectorAll. This will provide you with a NodeList, from which you can then select the specific element you wish to focus on.

```
function focusNext(currentInput, nextIndex) {
  if (currentInput.value.length === 1) {
    const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(`.code-input input`);
    if (nextIndex < nodes.length)
      nodes[nextIndex].focus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nth-child` indexes start at 1 not 0

```js
function focusNext(currentInput, nextIndex) {
  if (currentInput.value.length === 1) {
    const nextInput = document.querySelector(`input:nth-child(${nextIndex + 1})`);
    if (nextInput) {
      nextInput.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="code-input">
  <input type="text" @bind=code0 maxlength="1" onkeyup="focusNext(this, 1)">
  <input type="text" @bind=code1 maxlength="1" onkeyup="focusNext(this, 2)">
  <input type="text" @bind=code2 maxlength="1" onkeyup="focusNext(this, 3)">
  <input type="text" @bind=code3 maxlength="1" onkeyup="focusNext(this, 4)">
  <input type="text" @bind=code4 maxlength="1" onkeyup="focusNext(this, 5)">
  <input type="text" @bind=code5 maxlength="1">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, you were right. however it only works for the last ones, the very first one just loses the cursor..

Comment: It works for me in chrome

Comment: im using edge. could this be an issue?

Comment: same issue on opera